# T-SQL: how to update a rows that require some processing?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have a table `MessagingTemplates` and a column `[Subject]`. Text in the column is of the following format

```
Operations Portal - Task proposed
Operations vendor - Task rejected
Resources Portal - Late Task
```

All the values in that column have the above format. I'd like to write a stored procedure that will change the text to

```
[CompanyName] - Task proposed - [proposedDate]
[CompanyName] - Task rejected - [proposedDate]
[CompanyName] - Late Task - [proposedDate]
```

I'm thinking about something like

```
UPDATE MessagingTemplates
SET [Subject] = '[CompanyName] - ' + [Subject]  + ' - [proposedDate]'
WHERE MessageName IN ('TaskProposed, TaskRejected')  -- There are many more ...
```

Obviously, before updating I need to remove everything that comes before `-`

**UPDATE**:

It looks like I need more processing because for some row there are more than one `-`. In those cases, I need to retrieve only the text after the last `-`.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a one way trip you could simple preprocess Subject:

```
UPDATE MessagingTemplates
   SET Subject = RIGHT(@subject, LEN(@subject) - CHARINDEX('-',@subject,1) + 2)
```

and then run the query you have:

```
UPDATE MessagingTemplates
   SET Subject = CompanyName + Subject  + ' - ' + proposedDate
WHERE MessageName IN ('TaskProposed, TaskRejected') -- There are many more
```

assuming the CompnayName and proposedDate are actually other field so he table

EDIT: You comment clarifies your intend so it easy to use the quoted text as above.

UPDATE MessagingTemplates
       SET Subject = '[CompanyName]'  + Subject  + ' - [proposedDate]'
    WHERE MessageName IN ('TaskProposed, TaskRejected') -- There are many more

You can of course do it all in one update.

```
   UPDATE MessagingTemplates
       SET Subject = '[CompanyName]'  
                   + RIGHT(@subject, LEN(@subject) - CHARINDEX('-',@subject,1) + 2)  
                   + ' - [proposedDate]'
    WHERE MessageName IN ('TaskProposed, TaskRejected') -- There are many more
```

But if may have multiple ' - ' and want to key of the last you need to mix in REVERSE()

```
   UPDATE MessagingTemplates
       SET Subject = '[CompanyName]'  
                   + RIGHT(@subject, CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(@subject),1) + 2) 
                   + ' - [proposedDate]'
    WHERE MessageName IN ('TaskProposed, TaskRejected') -- There are many more
```

Comment: CompnayName, proposedDate, and many more are just texts. That's why they in brackets. Once a message is about to be sent, the caller of the table will replace those placeholder with the actual coming from various places.

Comment: got it. updated based on this. plus showing how do dot in one query AND how to do it if you may have multiple -s.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE  MessagingTemplates
SET     [Subject] = '[CompanyName] ' + SUBSTRING([Subject],
                                                 CHARINDEX('-', SUBJECT), 100)
        + ' - [proposedDate]'
WHERE   MessageName IN ( 'TaskProposed, TaskRejected' )  -- There are many more ...
```

Comment: I've applied your solution, which is more like what I am trying to accomplish. Now the problem is that some rows have more than one `-`. How do I skip any previous and take only the text after the last `-`?